# Taking care of the body

Tags: sources-mekorot, health-safety-shmira, vilna-gaon

I heard that the Gaon of Vilna wrote the following: normally, suffering comes to atone for past sins. But, when a person puts himself in a dangerous situation and suffers an accident due to this, this suffering is not related to a sin from the past, but it came to atone for the sin of putting himself in danger in that very situation, that is also a sin. Is that correct? Does any one know where he wrote it?

Comment: "but it came to atone for the sin of putting himself in danger in that very situation" - I've once read in Ohr Avigdor on Chovos HaLevavos that if one, for example, puts himself in a dangerous situation, by saying "Hashem will take care of me" - that is actually a sin. So yes, putting yourself in danger can be considered a sin, according to this point of view.